# Azure Kubernetes - Unable to Attach or Mount Volume for MongoDb

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, bitnami

We are deploying multiple Bitnami/MongoDB via helm on an AKS Cluster running on Kubernetes 1.19.7 on 4 Nodes (DS2_V2).

Each MongoDb is installed separately via helm install, however, completely randomically one of them fails and go in timedout condition reporting:

```
Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[datadir], unattached volumes=[datadir-db-token-p55m7]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

This is totally random and occuring since last week.
As Storage Class we use the default from aks, based on azure-storage-disk.
We have tried to change the volume binding move from WaitingForFirstConsumer to Immediate without success.

The full list of event is:

1. Successfully assigned tp-xxxxxx/xxxxxx-api-db-0 to aks-default-26759343-vmss000003
2. AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-adf7e23f-2264-4eb5-bc29-9e1707a3f5a9"
3. Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[datadir], unattached volumes=[datadir xxxxx-api-db-token-p55m7]: timed out waiting for the condition
4. MountVolume.WaitForAttach failed for volume "pvc-adf7e23f-2264-4eb5-bc29-9e1707a3f5a9" : timed out waiting for the condition
   5.Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[datadir], unattached volumes=[xxxx-api-db-token-p55m7 datadir]: timed out waiting for the condition

This lead to helm install to reach the timeout and then installation fails.

Comment: Is your pod in the same region as the PV? You may need to add affinity to fix it or use an external storage.

Comment: The cluster is located in West-Europe as the agent pool

Comment: Your Issue seems to be same as https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/94764. Can you please check in kubelet logs if the Persistent Volume was mounted after the timeout ? Please keep the volumeBindingMode = WaitingForFirstConsumer for the storage class otherwise your pv may get created in a different zone than the pod and cannot be mounted into the pod leading to unschedulable Pods.

Comment: Can it be you have too many volumes attached to the same instance? Azure virtual machines have a limit on how many disks can be attached at the same time. In case of `DS2_V2` this limit is 8

Comment: Can you share the chart and the YAML file you use to create the PV?

Comment: @Charles Xu We are installing multiple instances of Bitnami/MongoDB https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb   where we set architecture=replicaSet .

Comment: You need to share more details about the PV you use to mount.

Comment: Got the same issue, have you solved it @Slevin?

Comment: @GoonNguyen we started creating AKS cluster with 3 zones (we were just using one) and  while in contact with Microsoft seems that when this post was made there were some bug/issue broadly on AKS.  Since then we never experience the issue again.